# Mostrar imagen en la parte superior de la pagina cuando el codigo esta dentro de un web method.Asp,net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola comunidad realizo un cambio de imagen de acuerdo al proceso en que se encuentre mi formulario(Tipo multi stepForm) y me encuentro con este problema.

A través de un webMethod recibo un dataset y dentro de este consulto las tablas y datos que necesito **hasta aqui todo me lo hace correcto y me trae los datos que necesito sin errores** mi problema esta en como visualizar la imagen y colocarla arriba de mi formulario web ya que no se muestra. Aquí mi código de antemano gracias.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string Intervalo(int id_Persona, string Sucursal, int rol) 
    {
        Transacciones t = new Transacciones();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable tabla_Personas = new DataTable();
        DataTable tabla_imagenPasos = new DataTable();
        ds = t.Mostrar_Personas(id_Persona, Sucursal, rol);
        tabla_Persona = ds.Tables[0];            
        tabla_imagenPasos = ds.Tables[1];
        DataRow row = tabla_imagenPasos.Rows[0];
        Image imgPaso = new Image(); // creacion de control imagen
        imgPaso.ImageUrl = row[2].ToString();// direccion de la imagen           
        imgPaso.Visible = true;
        imgPaso.ImageAlign = ImageAlign.Top;
        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_Personas, Formatting.Indented);

        return datos;        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que estas llamando a tu metodo desde la pagina simplemente agregas la propiedad de la imagen:
//usando jquery
  $('#imagenUsuario').find('img').attr('src', imgUrl)

Agrego codigo de ejemplo

```js
var imgUrl = 'http://mx.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20180925130054/consejos-para-cuidar-a-un-gatito-recien-nacido-cs/0-601-526/cuidardgatito-t.jpg'

$('#btnAgregaImagen').click(function() {
  $('#imagenUsuario').find('img').attr('src', imgUrl)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imagenUsuario">
  <img />
</div>


<button id="btnAgregaImagen">Agrega imagen</button>
```